# Error using @Resource and @Service annotation in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have been trying to use @Resource and @Service annotations in Spring as follows.

Here is my service class

```
@Service("personService")
public class PersonService {
    protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("PersonService");
    // service methods here
}
```

And my controller class here

```
@Controller
public class PersonController {

    protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("controller");

    @Resource(name="personService")
    private PersonService personService;

    // controller methods
}
```

When I deploy this application on the jboss server, I am getting following error.

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.demoApp.service.PersonService from BaseClassLoader@1612c8f{VFSClassLoaderPolicy@b49448{name=vfsfile:/E:/servers/demoAppserver/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/jbossweb.sar/ domain=ClassLoaderDomain@d5f9b9{name=DefaultDomain parentPolicy=BEFORE parent=org.jboss.system.NoAnnotationURLClassLoader@11a9310} roots=[MemoryContextHandler@24324950[path= context=vfsmemory://5c4o066-473awx-gnqvtutg-1-gnqvu8rq-x real=vfsmemory://5c4o066-473awx-gnqvtutg-1-gnqvu8rq-x], FileHandler@2241655[path=jbossweb.sar context=file:/E:/servers/demoAppserver/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/ real=file:/E:/servers/demoAppserver/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/jbossweb.sar/], DelegatingHandler@27422898[path=jbossweb.sar/jasper-jdt.jar context=file:/E:/servers/demoAppserver/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/ real=file:/E:/servers/demoAppserver/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/jbossweb.sar/jasper-jdt.jar], DelegatingHandler@26532309[path=jbossweb.sar/jboss-web-service.jar context=file:/E:/servers/demoAppserver/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/ real=file:/E:/servers/demoAppserver/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/jbossweb.sar/jboss-web-service.jar], DelegatingHandler@23676237[path=jbossweb.sar/jbossweb.jar context=file:/E:/servers/demoAppserver/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/ real=file:/E:/servers/demoAppserver/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/jbossweb.sar/jbossweb.jar], DelegatingHandler@4513709[path=jbossweb.sar/jstl.jar context=file:/E:/servers/demoAppserver/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/ real=file:/E:/servers/demoAppserver/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/jbossweb.sar/jstl.jar], DelegatingHandler@28896918[path=jbossweb.sar/jsf-libs/jboss-faces.jar context=file:/E:/servers/demoAppserver/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/ real=file:/E:/servers/demoAppserver/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/jbossweb.sar/jsf-libs/jboss-faces.jar], DelegatingHandler@3657798[path=jbossweb.sar/jsf-libs/jsf-api.jar context=file:/E:/servers/demoAppserver/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/ real=file:/E:/servers/demoAppserver/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/jbossweb.sar/jsf-libs/jsf-api.jar], DelegatingHandler@4907609[path=jbossweb.sar/jsf-libs/jsf-impl.jar context=file:/E:/servers/demoAppserver/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/ real=file:/E:/servers/demoAppserver/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/jbossweb.sar/jsf-libs/jsf-impl.jar]]  delegates=null exported=[, org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload, com.sun.faces.mgbean, org.apache.taglibs.standard, org.apache.tomcat.util.net, org.apache.catalina.core, org.jboss.web.tomcat.security, org.apache.jasper.resources, org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.jaspi.modules, org.apache.tomcat.util.http, com.sun.faces, javax.faces.validator, org.apache.jasper.xmlparser, org.apache.catalina.util, org.apache.tomcat.util.log, org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt, org.apache.catalina.ant.jmx, org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.codegen, javax.faces.application, org.apache.catalina.startup, com.sun.faces.el, org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jasper, org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.modules, org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core, org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core, org.apache.catalina.manager.host, org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.config, org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql, com.sun.faces.lifecycle, org.apache.jasper.el, org.apache.naming.java, javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core, com.sun.faces.config, org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca, org.jboss.web.cluster.advertise, org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse, org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.fmt, org.apache.coyote.memory, org.apache.jasper.util, org.apache.taglibs.standard.lang.support, com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core, org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.sql, org.apache.catalina, com.sun.faces.ext.validator, org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.serialization, org.apache.tomcat.util.json, org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler, org.apache.catalina.ssi, org.apache.jasper.servlet, javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.sql, javax.faces.lifecycle, org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core, org.apache.taglibs.standard.lang.jstl.test, org.jboss.net.protocol.jndi, org.apache.taglibs.standard.lang.jstl.test.beans, org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.flow, org.apache.naming.resources, com.sun.faces.vendor, com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic, javax.faces.webapp, org.apache.coyote.http11.filters, javax.faces.convert, org.apache.tomcat.bayeux, org.apache.el.parser, com.sun.faces.spi, com.sun.faces.ext.component, org.apache.taglibs.standard.lang.jstl.parser, org.apache.catalina.mbeans, org.apache.catalina.security, javax.faces.render, com.sun.faces.config.configprovider, org.apache.taglibs.standard.tei, org.apache.catalina.servlets, org.apache.taglibs.standard.resources, org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql, org.jboss.web.tomcat.statistics, org.apache.naming.factory.webservices, javax.faces.event, org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.util, org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.diagnose, org.jboss.web.cluster, com.sun.faces.ext.render, META-INF.services, org.apache.jasper.security, com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic, org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.injection, com.sun.faces.resources, org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast, org.apache.taglibs.standard.extra.spath, org.apache.naming, org.apache.tomcat.util.http.mapper, org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.sso, org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv, org.apache.catalina.manager, org.jboss.web.rewrite, org.apache.tomcat.util.http.res, com.sun.faces.io, org.apache.taglibs.standard.functions, javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt, org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers, org.apache.jasper.tagplugins.jstl, org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt, org.apache.el.lang, org.apache.tomcat.util.res, javax.faces, org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.res, org.apache, javax.faces.component, org.apache.tomcat.util.digester, javax.faces.el, org.apache.taglibs.standard.lang.jstl, org.apache.catalina.manager.util, org.apache.tomcat.util, org.apache.naming.resources.jndi, org.jboss.web.tomcat.service, org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters, org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.jaspi, org.apache.catalina.loader, org.jboss.servlet.http, org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.env, org.apache.jasper.compiler, org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup, org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.util, com.sun.faces.application, org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.xml, org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.notification, org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.authenticators, org.apache.coyote, org.apache.catalina.authenticator, org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem, javax.faces.component.html, org.apache.el.util, com.sun.faces.config.processor, com.sun.faces.taglib, com.sun.faces.ext.taglib, org.apache.catalina.connector, org.apache.catalina.realm, org.apache.jasper.runtime, com.sun.faces.context, org.apache.cometd.bayeux, org.apache.jasper.tagplugins.jstl.core, javax.faces.context, org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt, org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.login, org.jboss.net.ssl, org.apache.jasper, org.apache.coyote.http11, org.jboss.web.php, org.apache.catalina.ant, org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler, org.apache.tomcat.bayeux.request, com.sun.faces.scripting, org.apache.tomcat.util.buf, org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch, org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.batch, org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler, org.jboss.web.tomcat.servlets, org.apache.jasper.compiler.tagplugin, org.apache.catalina.session, org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.injection, com.sun.faces.renderkit, org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml, javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv, org.apache.catalina.deploy, org.apache.catalina.valves, org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.res, javax.faces.model, com.sun.faces.util, org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.xml, META-INF, org.apache.tomcat.jni, org.apache.coyote.ajp, org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session, org.apache.tomcat.util.net.res, org.apache.naming.factory, org.jboss.web.tomcat.metadata, org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.impl, org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser, org.apache.el] <IMPORT-ALL>NON_EMPTY}}
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.injection.WebResourceHandler.loadXmlResourceEnvRefs(WebResourceHandler.java:267)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.injection.WebResourceHandler.loadXml(WebResourceHandler.java:307)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.processMetadata(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:544)
```

When I don't use these annotations the applications runs properly.

Comment: If I use @Component in place of @Service and @Autowired in place of @Resource it works properly. What is wrong with the @Service and @Resource annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to do with
`<context:annotation-config/>` or `<context:component-scan>` in your application context xml?

Comment: Yes. I have them in my application context xml. My controller is detected using @Controller annotation.

Comment: @Service is working but @Resource is not working. When I remove @Resource, my app runs but I get null pointer exception.

Comment: Are you sure your @Service is picked up? Do you have a base-package specified for component-scan? Have you tried replacing @Resource with @Autowired, does that work? Or do you _need_ @Resource? (will your app run in a non-spring environment?) How many appcontext.xmls do you have and how are they initialized?

Answer (score 1):

The exception is a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.demoApp.service.PersonService` this mean the problem is not that the injection does not work, it is because the PersonService class is not found.

You should check that it is correct deployed (the class and the annotations). And that you use the right annotations (for example imported the correct Service class, not someting like org.my.strange.project.Service)